# How to read a File and save specific occuring strings?

Tags: c++, qt, file, io, qt-creator

I need to read a file, which is an .asc document using QT Framework.

I need to check the file for specific Strings, for example "(Name)".
The Numbers after the specific String have to be saved in another .txt file.

So I tried to use a for loop connected with a `getline()` statement, whilst an if statement should be checking if the predefined String was found already.
If the String was found I am using a string variable `.assign()` method to input the whole matching line to another string.
But sadly it is still not working, maybe there is a logical failure, so I am asking for your help!

```
std::string line;
std::string search = "(Name)";
std::string content;
std::ifstream ifs("C:/PROG/EMS/LD1/analyse_led");
for(unsigned int curLine = 0; std::getline(ifs, line); curLine++) {
    if (line.find(search) != std::string::npos) {
        content.assign( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(line) ),
                        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    }
}
```

Of course I implemented all related include files above, thanks for your help!
If you need more information let me know in the comments.

Comment: I don't see any Qt classes or code!? May be easier with QFile and QString if you already use Qt anyway.

Comment: Thanks for yor help. @BoBTFish your solution worked.

Comment: @Jonas Since it worked for you, I moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` and `line` are both `std::strings`, just do

```
content = line;
```

or

```
content = std::move(line);
```

if you don't need to do anything else with `line` afterwards. (`line` will be empty after this).

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with `istreambuf_iterator`, but I'm sure it isn't going to work...